# Indian national with Malaysian Permanent resident

Tags: visas, indian-citizens, taiwan

I am an Indian national with Permanent Resident status working as a consultant Surgeon. I am Planning to visit Taiwan along with my friends in Rotary to attend the Rotary function. How do I apply for the tourist visa?

Comment: Are you currently in Malaysia?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question because the OP never returned to provide additional information